# Installing viso2 for getting odometry for Kinect SLAM

Tags: ros, slam, viso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm implementing basic version of 2D SLAM using Xbox Kinect and the following packages

- pointcloud_to_laserscan
- viso2
- gmapping

Fortunately, I was able to install pointcloud_to_laserscan by installing turtlebot, even gmapping is already present, but I found that there is no Wiki for downloading this package [viso2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2?distro=fuerte). I search many places to install using .rosinstall way but roslocate is **always** showing 404 error. I tried to even update roslocate but everything seems to be the same. I followed [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/9201/how-do-i-install-a-missing-ros-package/)answer.

My ROS version is fuerte and it is running in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59630/installing-viso2-for-getting-odometry-for-kinect-slam/) by [freadx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4069/freadx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To install a ROS package for which there is no debian package available, just download the sources somewhere inside your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and compile it.

As you can see on the [wiki page of viso2](http://ros.org/wiki/viso2), the sources for this package are on github: https://github.com/srv/viso2.git

To install the package, just cd into a directory that is in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, clone the repo and rosmake:

```
cd <my_ros_workspace>
git clone https://github.com/srv/viso2.git
rosmake viso2_ros
```

If you want to use a Kinect for visual odometry I would strongly recommend to use [fovis_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fovis_ros) instead of viso2 as it supports RGBD input. The installation is equivalent:

```
cd <my_ros_workspace>
git clone https://github.com/srv/fovis.git
rosmake viso2_ros
```

The roslocate calls fail for these packages as they are (not yet) released for groovy. roslocate uses URLs without a tag for the distribution which currently forward to groovy URLs (that don't exist for these packages).

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2